# Hashtags suggestions working 'react-draft-wysiwyg'

Tags: draftjs, draft-js-plugins, react-draft-wysiwyg

I'm using 'react-draft-wysiwyg' library and everything working goes well. I'm wondering if there is a way to add hashtags suggestions once the user starts to type the '#'?

```
<Editor
            editorState={editorState}
            wrapperClassName="main-wrapper"
            editorClassName="main-editor"
            onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
            mention={{
                separator: ' ',
                trigger: '@',
                suggestions: handleSuggestionsList(),
            }}
            hashtag={{}}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth looking at azangru's [hashtag-autocompletion-with-draftjs](https://github.com/azangru/hashtag-autocompletion-with-draftjs)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found how to add hashtags with selection using Draftjs API and local functions.
In this article, you can find the implementation: https://bigbite.net/insights/building-editor-draft-js-react/